# Wifi not working on Asus Vivobook 15 R504ZA on fresh Ubuntu 19.10 installation

Tags: drivers, wireless, asus, 19.10

Wi-Fi is not detected on my fresh Ubuntu 19.10 installation on an [Asus Vivobook 15 R504ZA](https://www.power.fi/tietotekniikka/tietokoneet/kannettavat-tietokoneet/asus-vivobook-15-r504za-ej723t-kannettava-tietokone/p-985790/) installation. The Settings > Wi-Fi page states "No Wi-Fi Adapter Found". The liveboot from a USB stick that I tried out before the installation had the Wi-Fi working fine.

Which driver do I need to install and how do I install it?

The output of the [wireless-info script](https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info) on my computer is shown here: https://pastebin.com/raw/MiWkNy34

Without Wi-Fi, my computer is without internet connection, so I will need to download installation files with another computer and copy files on a USB stick.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Please notice in your log file: "Failed to run INIT ucode: -110" Next, please follow the procedure in the duplicate.

Comment: @chili555, excellent, the answer to the question you referred to solved my problem. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Awesome! Glad it's working.